# how I can get the last 3 characters in the string link?

Tags: java

how I can get the last  3 characters in the string link ?

I have the link such as :

`"http://www.google.com"`

How I can get the **"com"** only ?
and put these characters in variable "String data type" ?

note : I'm new in java ,I'm develop the android app and must be get this code , please :\

Comment: Are you sure it will be always `.com`? Have you considered `.co.uk` or something else? Because in your case.. you can just print `.com` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `url` will end with `.XXX` (continuous extension)

```
String[] splitted = url.split("\\.");
return (splitted[splitted.length-1]); //will return the last string after the last "."
```

Where `url` is your `url` (`www.google.com` in this case).

**Note** that if the `url` is `http://www.google.com/` then the code will return `.com/`. So you need to perform a check if the result contains `/` character. (Hint: look for `contains` in the String API).

Comment: thank you alot ,,, also I want to ask you ?
this code is correct :

s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

Comment: My code, and the one you suggested will give you `.com` in the example you provided, but if the url is `http://www.google.com/` both of the codes will return `.com/` (with the '/') so you'll need to check in the result if it contains `/` and remove it manually. (See my answer again)

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the string, and make substring starting from position length-4 and take 3

Answer (score 0):

Get the last index of the character '.', from there increment once then go till there are no other characters or you reach a '/' character.